# Problems with encoding

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I'm using MySQL 5.1 and Susbsonic 3.0.0.3. Database and all tables are in cp1251. I have problems with saving russian symbols. After saving it looks like "?????". How i can setup subsonic to save symbols in cp1251?

P.S. With reading everything is ok.

Comment: Can you say me in what encoding Subsonic saves data?
i will try to set mysql parameter
init-connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved problem. I set parameter init-connect

```
init-connect=SET NAMES cp1251
```

But it is not good solution to this problem!